# Getting position holder

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have students' result data from 36 districts. I am trying to obtain top three position holders from each district with the help of **SQL Server** query. I am prartially succeeded in it through following query:

```
select 
  District, 
  ROLL_NO, 
  ENG, 
  URDU, 
  MATH, 
  SCI, 
  ISL , 
  (cast(Eng as int) + CAST(urdu as int)+ CAST(MATH as int) + CAST(SCI as int) + CAST(ISL as int)) as  TotalScore 
from G5G8
ORDER BY DISTRICT, TotalScore DESC
```

This query produces top 3 results but  output of all the other students also, but I want to get only top 3 position holders from each district (Total 36 x 3 = 108 records) 
Pls suggest what more should I add in this query.

**I am  using SQL Server 2008 R2**

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Could you please mention the database you are using?

Comment: And your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for a query like the following,

```
SELECT
    t.District,
    t.ROLL_NO,
    t.ENG,
    t.URDU,
    t.MATH,
    t.SCI,
    t.ISL,
    t.TotalScore,
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        District, 
        ROLL_NO, 
        ENG, 
        URDU, 
        MATH, 
        SCI, 
        ISL , 
        (cast(Eng as int) + CAST(urdu as int)+ CAST(MATH as int) + CAST(SCI as int) + CAST(ISL as int))as TotalScore
        rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY District ORDER BY TotalScore) 
    FROM 
        G5G8 
    ORDER BY 
        TotalScore DESC
    GROUP BY 
        District
) AS t
WHERE t.rowid <= 3
ORDER BY t.TotalScore
GROUP BY t.District
```

I could be clearer if I could know your table structure. However, you could take a look at [here](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/selecting-top-n-records-per-group).